# ZonedDateTime how to set min or max time?

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

How to change time of instatiated ZonedDateTime to f.e.: 'java.time.LocalTime.MIN' or 'java.time.LocalTime.MAX'?

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

This is good start: `ZonedDateTime startDate = date.withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);`

But It will be good to have: 
`ZonedDateTime startDate = date.withTime(LocalTime.Min);`

Comment: do you need that for a comparator?

Comment: I need to have date for between operation. I dont need a time.

Comment: this looks like an XY problem. why exactly do you think you need this?

Answer (score 4):

This is quite short for minimal value of Time in ZonedDateTime:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

It will cut off (set to zero): hours, minutes, seconds and nanos from ZonedDateTime.

And this for max value of Time in ZonedDateTime:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59).withNano(LocalTime.MAX.getNano());
```

Comment: For the max value, you can do with one less method call (and one less temporary object), as well as fewer magic values, if you do it this way: `ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).minusNanos(1);`

Comment: In my opinion it is to completed to use. I prefer longer way

Comment: What about days with leap seconds, when the last minute of the day has 61 seconds instead of 60?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is:

```
    System.out.println(date.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(date.getZone()));
    System.out.println(date.toLocalDate()
            .plusDays(1)
            .atStartOfDay(date.getZone())
            .minusNanos(1));
```

One might easily have expected `date.with(LocalTime.MIN)` and `date.with(LocalTime.MAX)` to do the job, and it may give you the desired result. Just beware that because of transition to summer time (DST) and other anomalies, there are (rare) cases where the time 00:00 (which is the definition of `LocalTime.MIN`) does not exist in that zone on that day. The above clearly takes that into account and also leaves your reader with no doubt about what happens in such a case.

However if you just need to compare dates, just get rid of the time of day and compare the dates:

```
    ZonedDateTime otherDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 2, 20, 13, 45, 0, 0,
                                ZoneId.of("America/Santa_Isabel"));
    if (date.toLocalDate().isAfter(otherDate.toLocalDate())) {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use .with(TemporalAdjuster).
You can adjust the TemporalAdjuster with TemporalAdjust.adjustInto(Temporal):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

Comment: It’s no poor suggestion, on the other hand it’s not enough to solve the OP’s problem.